# hibernate way in copying the data of the database to another database

Tags: hibernate

Is there any way in hibernate to get the actual underlying JDBC connection to create a new database, and then copy all the data from an existing “template” database to the new one?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
public boolean syncronize(Class hibernateClass, Session from, Session to) throws HibernateException
    {
            Transaction transaction = to.beginTransaction();
            List newData = from.createCriteria(hibernateClass).list();
            for (Iterator iter = newData.iterator(); iter.hasNext();)
                {
                    Object element = (Object) iter.next();
                    from.evict(element);
                    to.replicate(element,ReplicationMode.OVERWRITE);
                }
            transaction.commit();
     }
```